# Tuxguitar 1.3.1 no sound ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, tuxguitar

Once again, no sound in Tuxguitar. Before it updated, the TiMidity fix worked, running through the Gervill midi port. However, in the new tuxguitar update, that port is gone, along with the sound.

I have the alsa, oss, and jsa plugins installed and selected. I've tried what every other post on here has said, but I think this is a new issue arising from the 1.3.1 update.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same happened to me, and the only way I could make it work was installing the 1.3.2 version from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/).

If you want to do it, it's easy with a couple of hints.

## Installing

After compiling it myself, I realised there's another tar already compiled [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/files/TuxGuitar/TuxGuitar-1.3.2/). Click on the tuxguitar-1.3.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz.

Unpack somewhere, and you will see a `tuxguitar.sh` inside. Launching with `./tuxguitar.sh` everything works. By default it uses the "Gervill" thing that other answers say to use.

## Compiling tuxguitar from source

**warning**: I only recommend this if no other option worked. I guess there are other easier ways.

You will need mvn (sudo apt-get install maven), and a java version installed (it's likely you already have java 7 or 8, type `java -version` to find out).

At the moment, as the ubuntu package only lists up to 1.3.1, uninstall your current tuxguitar (and all the plugins).

Once you have downloaded the tar, this is what I did. I'm sure there are better ways, but this worked:

`tar zxvf tuxguitar-1.3.2-src.tar.gz
cd tuxguitar-1.3.2-src/build-scripts/tuxguitar-linux-x86_64-deb/
mvn install -DskipTests
cd target/
sudo dpkg --install tuxguitar-1.3.2-linux-x86_64.deb
/opt/tuxguitar/tuxguitar.sh`